# C: Program that prints a certain number of characters only

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on a program that, when specified by a number entered by the user, will only print out that number of characters. For example, if the user enters the number 10, then if 14 characters are entered (including newlines, blanks and tabs) only 10 characters will be printed. My code seems to work for the first three or so characters, then it prints out garbage. I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void findchars(char *abc, int number);

int main(void)
{
    char *array; // the actual array 
    int num; // number of characters to read, becomes array value

    printf("Number of characters:");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);

    array = (char *)malloc(num * sizeof(char));

    findchars(array, num);

    printf("The first %d characters: ", num);

    puts(array);

    free(array);

    return 0;
}

void findchars(char *abc, int number)
{

    int i; 

    printf("Type characters and I will stop at %d: ", number);

    for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        abc[i] = getchar();
    }

}
```

Comment: `puts` takes a string. You're not giving it a string.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc`. Also, `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: `abc` isn't `NULL` terminated. strings in C have to be terminated by the '\0' character

Comment: You have not allocated enough room for, or written, the required string terminator. Moreover you might be reading every `newline` too.

Comment: Note that `scanf_s("%d", &num);` is leaving a `newline` to be read by `getchar();` in your function. Announcing the result with `printf("The first %d characters: ", num);` does not print any `\n` newline, yet if you look at the output from the program, it has moved to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing non-zero-terminated array to puts. If you want your program to work just create your array 1 item bigger and add '\0' in the end.

Edit: like this

```
array = (char *)malloc((num+1) * sizeof(char));
```

and then right before `puts`:

```
array[num] = '\0';
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the help! I added you code to mine and it works fine, but it still skips the last character.

Comment: See the comment above about newline character.

Comment: I did that and it still skips the last character. Sample output is below:


How many characters should I read:7 (newline)
Start entering characters, and I will quit taking them at 7: he (newline)
Ll o (newline)
The first 7 characters you typed were:he(newline)
Ll

Comment: Just one idea to verify - if you are using Windows, newline is 2 chars.

Comment: I think that might be an issue with the newline. When I enter the number of characters to be read as 1, the program skips through until the end of the program, without letting the user enter anything.